# In UnitTest Thread.sleep(1300) is only waiting ~300ms

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, events, thread-sleep

I am trying to test that calling `SendMessage` after a set amount of time (in my case 1300ms) will give the correct result in the event handler. However `Thread.Sleep(1300)` is not waiting 1300ms, it only waits for about 300ms.

#### Unit Test

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using mvce;

namespace mvceTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Class1 c = new Class1();

            string finalResult = "";

            c.AnEvent += (o, entry) => { finalResult = entry; };

            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

            while (finalResult == "")
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1300);
                c.SendMessage("message");
            }

            DateTime end = DateTime.Now;

            Assert.AreEqual(1300, (end - start).Milliseconds);

            Assert.AreEqual("message", finalResult);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Class1

```cs
using System;

namespace mvce
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private readonly object _lock = new object();

        private event EventHandler<string> _anEvent;

        public event EventHandler<string> AnEvent
        {
            add
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    _anEvent += value;
                }
            }
            remove
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    _anEvent -= value;
                }
            }
        }

        public void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            _anEvent?.Invoke(this, message);
        }

    }
}
```

The output I get is

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<1300>. Actual:<302>.

Obviously I don't expect them to be equal, this is just for the example.

I have also tried `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1300).Wait();`, but I get the same result.

How can I get the test thread to wait the right amount of time? Why doesn't `Thread.Sleep` work?

Comment: How did you measure `~300ms`?

Comment: @SeM it's what the assert tells me.

Comment: @MattEllen This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Nkosi I have to test that the result of the event is affected by how long it takes for `SendMessage` to be called.

Comment: @MattEllen then I suggest you edit the question to clarify that. You would get better responses if that is made clear. Right now you are focusing more on the `Thread.Sleep` issue, which would put attention away from the actual problem. Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also I don't think `DateTime start = DateTime.Now;` and then using `(end - start).Milliseconds` will give you an accurate result.

Comment: @sem but will it be 1 second out? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @SᴇM Good catch. That is a very useful question.

Comment: @Nkosi if my example isn't minimal I don't know what you expect tbh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your assert you're using:

```
Assert.AreEqual(1300, (end - start).Milliseconds);
```

Try using the following instead:

```
Assert.AreEqual(1300, (end - start).TotalMilliseconds);
```

`TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds` :

> Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole
>   and fractional milliseconds.

`TimeSpan.Milliseconds`  :

> Gets the milliseconds component of the time interval represented by
>   the current TimeSpan structure.

The reason it is returning 300ms is because milliseconds component of your TimeSpan is in fact 300 milliseconds, but also the seconds component of your TimeSpan is 1 second.

Comment: Amazing. I didn't realise this is how DateTime worked. Thank you!

Comment: This will give an inaccurate result too (`Assert.AreEqual` will fail).

Comment: @SeM I'm not using AreEqual in the actual test, that was just to demonstrate what the difference is.

Comment: Then you should probably ask a question about what you are actually using.

Answer (score 1):

You should use TotalMilliseconds instead of Milliseconds.
Also, it's better to measure time using Stopwatch.

This code shows that thread is indeed sleeping for 1300ms:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 c = new Class1();

        string finalResult = "";

        c.AnEvent += (o, entry) => { finalResult = entry; };

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        while (finalResult == "")
        {
            sw.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1300);
            var ms = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine(ms);
            c.SendMessage("message");
        }
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine((end - start).TotalMilliseconds);
}
```